# windowsPhone8: how to convert rgb image into binary image in windowsphone8

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, grayscale, binary-image

i have converted rgb image into gray-scaled image, i know by using threshold to same code i can get true black and white(binary) image but i am facing issues while implementing in WP8. whatever threshold i specify, result is complete back image.(i have also tried various threshold values).
Here is rgb to grayscale code. please tell me how i should modigy this code to get binary image.

```
 private async void rgb2gray_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (takenImage != null)
                {
                    WriteableBitmap srcbitmp = takenImage.Source as WriteableBitmap;
                    byte[] srcpixels = new byte[4 * srcbitmp.PixelWidth * srcbitmp.PixelHeight];

                using (Stream pixelstream = srcbitmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
                {
                    await pixelstream.ReadAsync(srcpixels, 0, srcpixels.Length);
                }

                //create destination bitmap and pixel array
                WriteableBitmap dstbitmap = new WriteableBitmap(srcbitmp.PixelWidth, srcbitmp.PixelHeight);
                byte[] dstpixels = new byte[4 * dstbitmap.PixelWidth * dstbitmap.PixelHeight];

                for (int i = 0; i < srcpixels.Length; i += 4)
                {
                    double b = (double)srcpixels[i] / 255.0;
                    double g = (double)srcpixels[i + 1] / 255.0;
                    double r = (double)srcpixels[i + 2] / 255.0;

                    byte a = srcpixels[i + 3];

                    double z = (0.21 * r + 0.71 * g + 0.07 * b) * 255;

                    byte f = Convert.ToByte(z);


                        dstpixels[i] = f;
                    dstpixels[i + 1] = f;
                    dstpixels[i + 2] = f;
                    dstpixels[i + 3] = a;


                }
                //moving pixels into destination
                using (Stream pixelstream = dstbitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
                {
                    await pixelstream.WriteAsync(dstpixels, 0, dstpixels.Length);

                }
                dstbitmap.Invalidate();
                //display new bitmap

                takenImage.Source = dstbitmap;
            }
        }
```

Comment: the code looks fine, does the source image pixels yield any useful non zero data?

Comment: yes, what i want to know is how i can achieve complete black and white image through modification in this code?